# What happens to mage-cache-storage (local storage) when the browser window is closed?

Tags: session, cookie, local-storage

Magento uses mage-cache-storage (local storage) for local storage of visitor-specific content that enables ecommerce functions. The Expiration policy is session.

Suppose customer is using the website after logging in and went to checkout. Now this local storage object has the customer's information including the address.

What is going to happen if customer closes the browser window and then never opens the website on the same browser.
Does the browser will have this information and if no then how it is clearing it?

It would be great if someone can points me in the right direction,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are using local storage in that case, you can close the window it will persist if you open the same web site because its related to your site domain name but if you use session storage then it will go (removed) because the session storage will remove once we close the window for security reasons.